# Google Optimize - Weight 50/50, but impressions very lopsided

Tags: google-optimize

I recently integrated Google Optimize and verified that it's installed correctly through the Chrome extension.

I have a redirect experiment setup with only 2 variants (50/50), but one receives literally 99% of all traffic/impressions.

I am not sure what the issue is.

I have marketing campaigns that directs users to the landing page, so my url setting is "starts with: [www.website.com/"](http://www.website.com/%22) to capture traffic from users with utms in them.

Would Google Search (organic traffic), and Google Ads affect the distribution of the variants? I assume not, because Google Optimize would trigger independently?

I'd appreciate any input I could get. Thanks in advance!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ammm.png)